# How can I connect to SQL db in my PC using wamp from Raspberry PI 3 via WIFI?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

MY RP and my pc are connected to the same LAN (WIFI)

```
import pymysql
import MySQLdb
import time
import datetime
import Adafruit_DHT as dht

db = pymysql.connect("192.168.137.","root","","H_S")
cursor=db.cursor()
```

I got this message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "adc.py", line 17, in <module>
    db = pymysql.connect("198.168.137.1","root","","hop_S")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 327, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 629, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.137.1' (timed out)")
```

FIREWALL in my pc is disactivated 
and every thing is configured to accept external connections

Comment: I removed the Microsoft SQL Server tag and added the more appropriate mysql tag.

Comment: Your code says you try to connect to the IP address 169.254.168.44 , while the error message says you try to connect to IP 198.168.137.1 , so you need to figure out which IP address you should connect to, and make sure the code you are running tries to connect to that IP address. (And make sure you disable any firewall you have running on your MySQL server machine)

Comment: sorry i'm trying to connect to the ' 198.168.137.1' adress which my pc adress after i created an access poit where i installed wamp.
I tryed many solution but anything work for me

Comment: I wont to send my sensors data from my raspberry pi to my pc sql server via wifi